# Allowing Users To Download Completed Form

Tags: php, forms, pdf, png, jpeg

I'm new-ish to php and have a somewhat unique issue. I have a working form that posts to a page that displays data based on the user input.

I'm looking to allow a user to download the final product from the display page, making it easy to send over via email. I've never tried something like this, so I'm not sure what the best filetype would be. As long as it's easy to send over it doesn't really matter, could be a pdf jpg or png.

I've gone through a few tutorials about converting form data to pdf, but I'm having trouble implementing it and was wondering if anyone knows of a quick and simple way to go about this.

An quick example of the "display page" code (that I would like to be downloadable) is below.

```
Customer Name: <?php echo $_POST["customer_name"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a basic example of how your "final product" site can be coded. You'll need FPDF [(fpdf.org)](http://www.fpdf.org/) included.

```
require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pagesize = array(107, 199);
$pdf = new FPDF( 'P', 'mm', $pagesize );
$pdf->AddPage();

$Y_Fields_Name_position = 30;
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(120,0,'Customer Name:'.$_POST['customer_name'],0,1,'L',0);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(120,12,'Customer E-Mail:'.$_POST['customer_email'],0,1,'L',0);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(120,0,'Customer company:'.$_POST['customer_company'],0,1,'L',0);
$pdf->Output('FILENAME.pdf','D');
```

This will create a .pdf file and force it to download. Of course you can adjust the output to your needs, there's quite a good documentary available at fpdf.org's page. Remember that there mustn't be any other output on the page, so if you need to output data (echo or whatever), add above posted code to another file and add a button to your earlier page.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and really easy to integrate. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Looked at dompdf?

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

U can basically make a html page which will be transformed into a pdf file